# Iterate over character vector in dplyR summarise and use it to assign new column names

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a character vector with the name of my variables:

```
variables -> c("w", "x", "y", "z")
```

I need to create a function that calculates the mean of every variable for a specified parameter (as below for alpha). However, it doesn't rename the columns with the iterating variable names and does not reduce the `alpha` columns down to one on the left.

```
calc <- function(df,
                 parameter,
                 iteration,
                 variables){
      variable <- sym(variables[iteration])
      mean <- df %>% group_by(.dots = parameter) %>% 
              summarise(variable = mean(!!variable),sd_variable = sd(!!variable))
      return(mean)
    }
    
means <- map_dfc(1:length(variables), ~calc(df = input,
                                           parameter = "alpha",
                                           iteration = .,
                                           variables = variables))
```

Ideally the output df (`means`) would look like this:

```
alpha | w | sd_w | x | sd_x | y | sd_y | z | sd_z |
```

Here is what the input df looks like:

```
    structure(list(time = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 999.5, 999.6, 
999.7, 999.8, 999.9, 1000), w = c(10, 10.0057192322758, 10.0198266325956, 
10.040096099625, 10.0637654242843, 10.087779652849, 0.889708853982268, 
0.890916575744663, 0.892121389863897, 0.89332329218135, 0.894522278550115, 
0.895718344834999), x = c(10, 11.0467963604334, 12.1782709261765, 
13.3728962503142, 14.6035317074526, 15.8398164069251, 62.6631746231113, 
62.6583134156356, 62.6534565303638, 62.648604016965, 62.6437559251575, 
62.6389123047088), y = c(10, 9.89605687874935, 9.59253574727296, 
9.11222320249057, 8.48917353431654, 7.76447036695841, 0.00833796964522317, 
0.00835876233547079, 0.00837957883570158, 0.00840041916631544, 
0.00842128334742553, 0.00844217139885453), z = c(10, 9.05439359565339, 
8.21533762023494, 7.48379901688836, 6.85562632179817, 6.3231517466183, 
-7.50539460838544, -7.48234149534558, -7.45927733670319, -7.43620225192078, 
-7.41311636057114, -7.39001978233681), alpha = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), beta = c(0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), eta = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), zeta = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), lambda = c(0.95, 
0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95
), phi = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), kappa = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ode_outputs..iteration.. = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c("1", 
"1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "3.9995", "3.9996", "3.9997", 
"3.9998", "3.9999", "3.10000"), class = "data.frame")
```

Ideally the function would use dplyr and/or baseR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, there's no need to iterate over columns.  It can all be done directly in `dplyr`...

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(alpha) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(
      c(w, x, y, z), 
      list(mean=mean, sd=sd)
    ), 
    .groups="drop"
  ) %>% 
  rename_with(function(x) str_sub(x,1,1), ends_with("mean"))
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  alpha      w    w_sd     x    x_sd       y      y_sd     z   z_sd
  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1   0.1 10.0   0.0345   12.8 2.20    9.14    0.875      7.99 1.38  
2   0.5  0.893 0.00225  62.7 0.00908 0.00839 0.0000390 -7.45 0.0432
```